# How do I change the height of my header image in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make one of those full-width header images (that takes about 25% height of the page) for this website. I'm using bootstrap for one of the first times and I can't figure out how to change the height of the image/container. I've tried using the "h-25" class and then also just tried doing an inline style. I've also even tried making a full CSS file to overwrite the bootstrap file (by setting .container-fluid {height:25%;}). No matter what I do I can't make the image change height.

```
        <div class="container-fluid p-0 h-25">
            <img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/AudienceSet+Tvs_darkened.JPG" class="img-fluid" height="25%;" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SSS</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">The Party<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Current Stadium</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">RSVP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Stadium History
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2017 Stadium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2018 Stadium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2019 Stadium</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

The container is at the top, however I've also included the navbar section incase you need some context as to where the image ends.

Comment: I can't see the top of the parent `div` that contains the image _ Does it have any classes other than `container-fluid` (which I'm assuming from your question text) ?

Comment: Check that the outer div on the img isn't limiting / forcing its size or something? Also yes, pls provide more complete code

Comment: Bootstrap utilities like `h-25` will only work in relation to the height of a parent `div`

Comment: @inputforcolor no its just a fluid-container (sorry not sure why I didn't paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on how you want to achieve 25% of the page for the header image but `height` attributes coded as percentages need a parent `div` with a stipulated height. The same is true of Bootstrap utility classes like `h-25` _

In this solution I recreated your code with a fixed header area and fixed `nav` aswell _ The result is a fully responsive header and nav which you can see here >>>
https://inputforcolor.net/stackover/adamtest/test.html

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 18rem;
}

.header {
    height: 12rem;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.headerImage { 
    height: 12rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    top: 12rem;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid header">
    <div class="row">
       <img class="headerImage" src="stadiumLarge.jpg" alt="stadium header">
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
```